# How to remove certain words from rows in a dataset - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataset

In my dataset, there is a column called AdminRegion2, and it has thousands of different values, each in a different row, they are all counties in the USA. I need to remove certain words from each of the county names so I can link the dataset to a GeoJSON file.

[image]

There are counties where these words are written after the name "Borough, Census Area, or County". I need to remove all three words from each row that might contain either. So that it is just "Baldwin"

This is code for Census Area I tired but all the counties which have census area at the end still have it. I don't know why it is not working.

```
only_counties = usa_only[usa_only['AdminRegion2'].str.contains("", na = False)]
only_counties = only_counties['AdminRegion2'].str.strip().str.replace("Census Area", '')
only_counties.to_csv("counties_only.csv")
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `only_counties = usa_only[usa_only['AdminRegion2'].str.contains("", na = False)]`?

Comment: I am trying to get the dataset to only show county data. because it contains data for state and county levels. And that line of code works.

Comment: Okay. I don’t really get it without seeing a sample for a state level, but I’ve changed my answer to work with the only_county data.

Comment: Gave me an error, I posted the error under your answer.

Comment: See below. I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
only_counties = usa_only[usa_only['AdminRegion2'].str.contains("", na = False)].copy() # now only_counties is a sliced copy of usa_only, not a view

only_counties['AdminRegion2'] = only_counties['AdminRegion2'].str.replace(' County', '')
only_counties['AdminRegion2'] = only_counties['AdminRegion2'].str.replace(' Census Area', '')
only_counties['AdminRegion2'] = only_counties['AdminRegion2'].str.replace(' Borough', '')
```

That should do the trick

Comment: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Ah, yes. Slicing can have that result. Try making a `.copy()` of your slice for `only_counties`. Now `only_counties` is a filtered copy of `usa_only` and not a filtered view.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
usa_only['AdminRegion2']=usa_only['AdminRegion2'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' Borough', '').replace(' Census Area', '').replace(' County', ''))
```

Comment: Error again, I don't understand why.

Comment: usa_only['AdminRegion2']=usa_only['AdminRegion2'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(' Borough', '').replace(' Census Area', '').replace(' County', ''))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

Comment: Can you confirm that column 'AdminRegion2' includes areas only in text (no numeric values)?

Comment: Yes definitely only strings